# How to check if all elements of a numpy array have integer values?

Tags: python, numpy

As the title says, it is **not** about `type` of elements. I need to be sure that the `values` of elements are integers, i.e.

```
np.array([1, 2, 3])
np.array([1., 2.0, 9/3])
```

must both give `[True, True, True]` after the 'Are they integers?'-checking.

Is there a clean and pythonic/numpyic way of doing this?

I've tried some many-lines-combinations such as:

```
isinstance(x, (int, np.integer)) 
#or
(1.0).is_integer()
```

but they are cumbersome and ugly.

Comment: I've made some progress in this regard. There is a standalone numpy function now available. Let's see if it makes it to numpy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I use is this `quantity % int(quantity) == 0`

Comment: this doesn't work for `v` such that `int(v) == 0` though

Answer (score 2):

One More Way:

```
>>> x = np.array([1.,2.0,9/3])
>>> [not (i%1) for i in x]
[True, True, True]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a oneliner using `is_integer()`:

```
>>> x = np.array([1., 2.0, 9/3])
>>> all([i.is_integer() for i in x])
True
```

Comment: I have added one line solution using  `is_integer()`, which is not cumbersome.

Comment: `all(i.is_integer() for i in x)` is 'more correct'.

remove the [] and it will be faster (i.e. stop at the first non integer encounter). There is no point in creating a temporary list.